# Como fracionar colunas/dados com um limite específico?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, dataset

Olá, amigos!

Atualmente faço uma pesquisa científica no ramo da IA, o Machine Learning - Classificação, usando a linguagem Python.

Em vista disso, eu tenho alguns dados para desenvolver um algoritmo, que será usado para treinar e testar a minha máquina. Porém são mais de 300.000 e, por estar alocando muito dado numa única variável, meu ambiente de desenvolvimento sofre erro de memória.

A minha estratégia é fracionar esse DataFrame e impor um limite, mas procurei e não encontro nada.
O objetivo é pegar esses 300.000 dados e limitar para 5.000 ou 10.000. Assim consigo uma quantidade boa para treinar minha máquina sem sofrer erro de memória.

Vocês têm ideia de como eu faço isso?

Comment: Use o parâmetro [nrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) para limitar o números de linhas a serem lidas:`read_csv(..., nrows=5000)`

Comment: Augusto, achei isso bem interessante.
Mas tem como eu setar esse limite isso dentro da variável? Ao invés só de ler? Porque eu preciso que concatene com esse limite que eu impus...

Comment: Parcialmente? Você quer pegar linhas aleatórias? Se for o caso vai ter que colocar uma amostra mínima de dados e um [mcve] pois dependendo do formato da tabela é um processo.

Comment: Não kkkkkk era pra eu criar outro parágrafo, mas acabei dando enter, me desculpe... eu editei, pode reconsiderar a pergunta, por favor?

Comment: Preciso ver o que está fazendo. Tenho quase certeza que você quer uma fatia dos dados, mas não tenho como afirmar ou indicar o melhor caminho sem ver o código.

Comment: Augusto, deu tudo certo! Eu tinha colocado o número errado.
Muito obrigada por sua ajuda e tempo, me serviram e me salvaram demais!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode pode determinar um valor pro chunksize

```
import pandas as pd

# tamanho da fatia
tamanho = 5000

for fatia in pd.read_csv('./arquivo.csv', chunksize = tamanho):
    # seu código aqui
```

Comment: Também acho que é isso que ela quer, mas sem o MCVE eu não arrisquei. Toma meu +1 pela coragem de codificar as cegas.

Comment: @AugustoVasques kkkkk, fui só porque era 'pouco' trabalhoso. Agradecido pelo upvote!

Comment: É isso mesmo, gente! Na real essa alternativa do chunksize eu não conhecia, achei bem interessante... mas a ajuda do Augusto já me foi bem útil! 
Obrigada aos dois e perdão por não ter sido tão clara :)